# k-means with selected initial centers

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to k-means clustering with selected initial centroids. 
It says [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)
 that to specify your initial centers:

```
init : {‘k-means++’, ‘random’ or an ndarray}
```

If an `ndarray` is passed, it should be of shape (`n_clusters`, `n_features`) and gives the initial centers.

My code in Python:

```
X = np.array([[-19.07480000,  -8.536],
              [22.010800000,-10.9737],
              [12.659700000,19.2601]], np.float64)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init=X).fit(data)
# print km
centers = km.cluster_centers_
print centers
```

Returns an error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Explicit initial center position passed: performing only one init in k-means instead of n_init=10
  n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
```

and return the same initial centers. Any idea how to form the initial centers so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default behavior of `KMeans` is to initialize the algorithm multiple times using different random centroids (i.e. the [Forgy method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Initialization_methods)). The number of random initializations is then controlled by the `n_init=` parameter ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans)):

> **n_init** : int, default: 10
>
> Number of time the k-means algorithm will be run with different
>   centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of
>   `n_init` consecutive runs in terms of inertia.

If you pass an array as the `init=` argument then only a *single* initialization will be performed using the centroids explicitly specified in the array. You are getting a `RuntimeWarning` because you are still passing the default value of `n_init=10` ([here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L307-L312) are the relevant lines of source code).

It's actually totally fine to ignore this warning, but you can make it go away completely by passing `n_init=1` if your `init=` parameter is an array.