# Using K-Means with predefined centers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm running a KNN classifier whose feature vectors come from a K-Means classifier (more specifically, `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans`). Since the K-means starts with random points every time I'm getting different results every time I run my algorithm. I've stored the cluster centers in a separate `.npy` file from a time where results were good, but now I need to use those centers in my K-means and I don't know how.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862334/k-means-with-selected-initial-centers) advice, I tried to use the cluster centers as starting points like so:

`MiniBatchKMeans.__init__(self, n_clusters=self.clusters, n_init=1, init=np.load('cluster_centers.npy'))`

Still, results change every time the algorithm is run.

Then I tried to manually alter the cluster centers after fitting the data:

`kMeansInstance.cluster_centers_ = np.load('cluster_centers.npy')`

Still, different results each time.

The only other solution I can think of is manually implementing the predict method using the centers I saved, but I don't know how and I don't know if there is a better way to solve my problem than rewriting the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess fixing the `random_state` will do the job.

See [API docu](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mini batch k-means only considers a **sample** of the data.

It uses a random generator for this.

If you want deterministic behaviour, fix the random seed, and prefer algorithms that do not use a random sample (i.e., use the regular k-means instead of mini-batch k-means).